# initializing ctypes string object

Tags: python, casting, ctypes

Although been reading some questions about similar subject, I couldn't figure out what was the point in my case ... I have a C structure defined as follows in my library header:

```
#define CLT_MAX_SIZE        16
#define MSG_MAX_SIZE        512

typedef struct
{
    LOG_LEVEL      m_level;
    char           m_text[MSG_MAX_SIZE];
    char           m_client[CLT_MAX_SIZE];
} LOG_Msg;
```

While writing a Python wrapper for this library, I've came to trouble handling this structure:

```
class Message(Structure):
    """ """

    _fields_ = [
                ("m_level", c_int),
                ("m_text", c_char_p*MSG_MAX_SIZE),
                ("m_client", c_char_p*CLT_MAX_SIZE)
               ]
```

Problem is I couldn't write a correct **init** method for this class. I'd like to have it respecting the following prototype:

```
def __init__(self, level, client, text):
    """ """
    self.m_level = c_int(level)
    self.m_text = **???**
    self.m_client = **???**
```

I've tried to use ctypes cast() and create_string_buffer() methods, but didn't manage to initialize the both text fields yet. Must have missed something somewhere, but no idea qo far ...

Any tip would be welcome ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from ctypes import *

class Message(Structure):

    MSG_MAX_SIZE=128
    CLT_MAX_SIZE=64

    _fields_ = [
        ("m_level", c_int),
        ("m_text",  type(create_string_buffer(MSG_MAX_SIZE))),
        ("m_client", type(create_string_buffer(CLT_MAX_SIZE)))
    ]

print Message.m_text
print Message.m_client


t = Message(100, 'abcdef' ,'flurp')

print t
print t.m_text
```

When you print Message.m_text and Message.m_client you'll see they're the right types:

```
<Field type=c_char_Array_128, ofs=4, size=128>
<Field type=c_char_Array_64, ofs=132, size=64>
```

But you can create the object and use the fields as normal Python strings with boundry limits.

Comment: `create_string_buffer` is a convenience function of sorts. But there's not much point in allocating the buffer just to get at the type. Use `c_char * MSG_MAX_SIZE` to create the array type.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it's exactly what was missing !